# Silverlight like animation library for .net projects

Tags: .net, silverlight, dll

In Silverlight presented a lot of different animations. My project does not use Silverlight, but it requires the use of similar animations. Need Silverlight like animation library for .net projects. Any ideas?

Comment: Try WPF - it shares many things with Silverlight, including animations.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Windows Presentation Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754130.aspx) technology - this is the alternative for desktop applications, where Silverlight is a subset of functionality exposed by this framework.

Comment: Need library for calculation animations parametres, which is not tied to specific technology (WPF, silverlight, etc).

Comment: What do you mean calculating animation parameters?  do you mean the easying calculations?  The only thing the animations do in silverlight is transform a start value to an end value relative to a time with or without a function applied to it...